# How to make simple HTML page more responsive?

Tags: html, css

So I've been tinkering with a REALLY simple web page (and this is why this is painful for me - it's a simple page) and I've been trying to make it responsive. I sort of had it looking right on a mobile screen, but the more I tweaked my code, the worse it got on other sizes.

So..I really hope that I'm not asking TOO much - but again the page is super simple, so this might be simple to answer..so I'll just jump in and ask a few questions :/

I want the page's big call to action image to disappear on a phone screen, and I'm trying to get the logo to center and the phone number to center right under it. I'm trying to get the bullet points images to center above the two lines of text..and the contact form to just fall in right below it (contact form was working just fine it seemed, so no big question there)

I'll link a live copy of the page as a reference - and a link to a page I've been mimicking in case it helps.

http://lab.blacksunresearch.com/ is my page
http://landing.trugreen.com/growth29 is the page im mimicking (sort of)

Again, I hope it doesnt sound like a TON of stuff, but the page is so simple, I'm probably only missing a few lines of code in my media queries

Thanks!

Edit: Moose, emoticon removed - also, I did ask a question - "How do I make this page more responsive?"

Comment: You should post relevant snippets of your code here, instead of just links to live pages that may change later.

Comment: Please ask a question. Questions have question marks at the end.

Comment: And you should remove the emoticon from the title.

Answer (score 1):

Open their CSS and look at parts with media-queries. There is what you want.
There are only 2 css which you should look through:
**themeform.css
themeresponsive.css**

Comment: Thanks, I just downloaded that page, and I'm opening up the files now to look closer

Answer (score 0):

You have to include some css to make it responsive **( Custom css , Jquery ,Jquery Mobile , Bootstrap etc)** . Or you can simply put some **Media Queries** where you want your webpage to Act differently, ie responsive .